# Any url typed on the address bar navigates back to the root url in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

The routing works perfectly if one click on any of the anchor tags. The problem occurs only if the user manually types the url on the address bar

For example, 
If one click on `sign in link` from the top navigation bar of the web page, then angular is correctly loading the `sign in component`, but if the user types `http://localhost:4200/sign-in`, it loads the `home component`

Specification

Ubuntu 17.10
Node 6.11.4
NPM 5.5.1

The code of the application is below

src/app/app.router.ts

```
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { SignUpComponent } from './sign-up/sign-up.component';
import { SignInComponent } from './sign-in/sign-in.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { Route } from '@angular/router';

export const routes: Route[] = [
  { path: 'sign-up', component: SignUpComponent},
  { path: 'sign-in', component: SignInComponent},
  { path: 'admin', pathMatch: 'full', loadChildren: 'app/admin/admin.module#AdminModule'},
  { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: 'app/user/user.module#UserModule'},
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
];
```

src/app/app.component.html

```
<top-navigation></top-navigation>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

src/app/shared/top-navigation/top-navigation.component.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">RS</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText"
    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li *ngIf="isLoggedIn" class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/dashboard']" >Dashboard</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- SIGNED IN USER -->
    <div *ngIf="isLoggedIn" class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        {{currentUser.username}}
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
        <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/me" routerLinkActive="active">Me</a>
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        <a class="nav-link" (click)="authService.logout()">Logout</a>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- [/END] SIGNED IN USER -->

    <!-- NO USER -->
    <div *ngIf="!isLoggedIn" class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/admin']">Sign In</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
```

src/index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this happening while using `ng serve` or when serving your code from a server?

Comment: This is happening when one uses `ng serve`

Comment: Can you try to enable the trace to see If there is an error? 
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      enableTracing: true
    })],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

Comment: Try adding a `pathMatch: 'full'` to the sign-in and sign-up routes. My guess is that Angular isn't able to match these routes and therefore uses the last matching route.

Comment: It sounds like it's treating the "on click" event of your links differently than if you go directly to the URL (by typing it in the address bar). I don't know specifically how or why - but could it be that it's firing a different route based on *how* the URL is being accessed? That's the only logical explanation because 2 identical URL's cannot produce different results if they are executing the same routing logic in a framework.

Comment: @masterfloda I tried adding `pathMatch: full`, but it did not yield any results. Angular is not able to match any routes in my case

Comment: @Andy The routes fired in both the cases are the same, but it works only in the case of click event

Comment: If you start up a new ng5 project using the CLI, and then quick add some routes according to the angular documentation https://angular.io/guide/router - can you make that work? If it works, then just compare the differences. If that doesn't work, can it be Ubuntu related on how it serves static files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the config `router` to  `useHash` or make url `rewrite`.

Following the command to solve this situatoin that `rewrite` (manage state).

```
$ npm install http-server -g
$ npm install -g spa-http-server
$ http-server --push-state
# ↑ it would solve the state flush problem.
```

Another way, use `{useHash:true,enableTracing:true}` in your `RouterModule` config.

```
config = {useHash:true,enableTracing:true};

imports:[RouterModule.forRoot(routes,config),]
```

Comment: Thank you, placing `{useHash:true,enableTracing:true}` in the `RouterModule` config worked for me

Comment: @RachChen Angular is supposed to work without the hash on modern browsers as well. It's odd that OP would require as he is using modern browsers

Comment: @CodyBugstein Hi,Cody. it's pretty odd to encounter this situation when the url strategy default is null.

See the source code of `angular/router`,the default would disable the `useHash` because of `null` value, so browser is switched enable manually.

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.0.1/packages/router/src/router_module.ts#L239-L270

Answer (score 1):

This is not specific to your problem but you should remove `href="#"` from links. Can you try this. Instead of `{ path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: HomeComponent},`
 
try like this
`{ path:'home', component: 'HomeComponent' }
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }`.

Comment: I did try that, but the results were the same

Answer (score -1):

I believe you haven't added the `base` element into your index.html.

According to Angular documentation, you should add a `<base>` element to the index.html as the first child in the  tag to tell the router how to compose navigation URLs.

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: There is a <base href= "/"> in the index.html file

Comment: If I remove the base href, I get 404s for the bundle files (which makes sense) but not a redirect to the home component.